# Common Lisp: How to rename a symbol when exporting or importing?

Tags: common-lisp

I need standard CL package symbol names (including those of NIL and T) to be in lower case in another package.

I've found the obvious number of required chars increasing solution to posting a question on Stackoverflow although this is perfectly understandeable using DEFMACRO for functions only.

Comment: CL is not case-sensitive. Why do you need that?

Comment: You can use [`readtable case` and `*print-case*`](https://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/22_accb.htm) to make the printer print symbols in lower case but that's not going to change how they're represented internally.

Comment: @Manfred: Symbols are internally case sensitive. (find-symbol "FOO") and (find-symbol "foo") will return different symbols, if they exist.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this: a symbol's name is an attribute of the symbol, so the name of the symbol `nil` is `"NIL"` and there's no way you can change this (especially not for `nil`!).  Symbols also have only one name.

---

A question to ask, as mentioned in a comment is: do you need the symbol's name to actually *be* lowercase, or do you just want to be able to type it in lower case and have it print in lowercase?  Almost always the latter is enough, and you can do this by controlling two parameters.

The variable [`*print-case*`](https://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/v_pr_cas.htm) controls how the printer prints the names of symbols.  If you set it to `:downcase` then they will be printed in lower-case when they can be so printed unambigiously.

Readtables, which control the reader, then have an attribute controlled by the accessor [`readtable-case`](https://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_rdtabl.htm) which controls what they do.  This has several options, but the default readtable has it be `:upcase` which will automagically make symbol-names typed in lowercase be interned as uppercase symbols, which is usually what you want.

These two parameters interact in fairly complicated ways in order to make sure that things are printed readably.  This is described [here](https://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/23_ab.htm) for the reader and [here](https://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/22_accb.htm) for the printer.

The consequence of all this is that if you set `*print-case*` to `:downcase` and don't change anything else, the language will behave for most purposes as though symbols had lowercase names, with the exception being when you actually need to write code which reasons about symbol names.

In particular:

```
> *print-case*
:downcase

> nil
nil

> (symbol-name 'nil)
"NIL"

> (eq 'nil 'NIL)
t

> (eq 'foo 'FOO)
t

> (symbol-name 'foo)
"FOO"
```

The time when this hurts in practice is when you need to deal with names from languages which think that `NamesLikeThis` are better than `names-like-this`.  The best approach to that is probably to write functions to turn one convention into the other, but other than that it's just going to be a bit painful.

---

There is at least one *non-portable* approach to dealing with this problem, which is to allow symbols to have 'nicknames'.  This is described by its author as 'a broken toy' and that's what it is.  It can be found [here](https://tfeb.github.io/#symbol-nicknames), and works for a couple of implementations.  One of its examples is creating a package which contains lowercase nicknames for all the standard CL symbols.  However this doesn't in fact solve most of the problem, because looking up a nickname returns the symbol it is a nickname for.  So for instance, after `(setf (nickname-symbol "grot") 'grot)` then `(symbol-name (find-symbol "grot"))` will be `"GROT"`.  I would advise against using this system, because it's fragile and nonportable.

Comment: Thanks! I actually need the names to be case-sensitive in a toy compiler on top of CL. Guess I'll break it further then.

Answer (score 2):

> I need standard CL package symbol names (including those of NIL and T) to be in lower case in another package.

For that you would need to create **new** symbols with the same names, but lowercase names, in a different packages.
Symbols have only one (case sensitive) name internally and the symbol is the same object, possibly accessible from different packages.

If you want to have a Symbol with internally a name with a different case, then you need to create a new symbol.